# Prove that if $M$ is rotation matrix, then so is $TMT^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Prove that if $M$ is rotation matrix, then so is $TMT^{-1}$

I already proved that the determinant and eigenvalues are the same for $M$ and $TMT^{-1}$, but I'm not sure how to prove they are both rotations.  Do i need to write out the matrix and its components, or is their a rotation equation/relationship I can use to show they are both rotations.

T is any invertible matrix

Comment: What is your *precise* definition for a rotation matrix?

Comment: definiton for rotation matrix is a matrix R that rotates any vector v over θ . components for this matrix are cosθ and  sinθ

Comment: What exactly is $T$? Any invertible matrix?

Comment: Yes T is any invertible matrix

Comment: are you considering vectors in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: It's _not true_ that if $M$ is a $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix and $T$ is a $2 \times 2$ invertible matrix, then $TMT^{-1}$ is a rotation matrix....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

M is rotation matrix so ,$T^{-1}$exist $$|M|=1,\\M_{\alpha}M_{\beta}=M_{\alpha+\beta} ,\\M_{\alpha}^n=M_{n\alpha}\\M_{\alpha}^{-1}=M_{-\alpha}$$
check these properties for $TMT^{-1}$
$$|TMT^{-1}|=|T|.|M|.|T^{-1}|=|T|.1.\dfrac{1}{|T|}=1\\$$$$
TM_{\alpha}T^{-1}.TM_{\beta}T^{-1}=TM_{\alpha}M_{\beta}T^{-1}=TM_{\alpha+\beta}T^{-1}\\$$$$
(TM_{\alpha}T^{-1})^n=TM_{\alpha}T^{-1}.TM_{\alpha}T^{-1}.TM_{\alpha}T^{-1}...TM_{\alpha}T^{-1}=TM_{\alpha+\alpha+\alpha+...}T^{-1}=TM_{n\alpha}T^{-1}\\$$$$
(TM_{\alpha}T^{-1})^{-1}=(T^{-1})^{-1}M_{\alpha}^
{-1}T^{-1}=TM_{-\alpha}T^{-1}$$

Comment: As Travis points out in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2293504/265466), below, a rotation matrix must preserve lengths (and angles). That condition is not covered anywhere in your answer—$|TMT^{-1}|=1$ only ensures that *areas* are preserved.

Answer (score 5):

The claim is false in general. If one takes $$M = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$$ (anticlockwise rotation by $90^{\circ}$) and $$T = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&\lambda}$$ (dilation by $\lambda$ in the $y$-direction). Then, $$TMT^{-1} \pmatrix{1\\0} = \pmatrix{0\\ \lambda} .$$
In particular, unless $\lambda = \pm 1$, we see that multiplication by $TMT^{-1}$ does not preserve lengths and so is not a rotation matrix.

Comment: Travis, could we say that the claim is true only for orthogonal $T$?

Comment: It's true for orthogonal $T$, but that's not all: It's also true for (nonzero) real multiples of the identity matrix, and therefore, and therefore for products of orthgonal matrices and dilations. These products comprise the *conformal orthogonal* group $CO(n, \Bbb R)$, whose members you might call *conformal orthogonal matrices* or *similarity matrices* (since the action of any element of this group on $\Bbb R^n$ takes any object to a similar object).

Comment: Ok, I see..thank you for the additional explanation ..

Comment: In fact, it's a nice exercise to show that this is all, provided that we interpret "rotation matrix" to mean "special orthogonal matrix".

Answer (score 2):

Check that $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} =  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 \\
1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$.

So it seems not to be true for **some** $T $ invertible.

And determinant of this result matrix $= 1$ and eigenvalues $+i,-i$ as for the middle rotation matrix (rotation by $ \pi /2 $) but the result matrix is not a rotation matrix.